# WIndows 7 install failed

Tags: installation, windows-7

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and I want to install Windows 7 (I have no interest in keeping Ubuntu on the computer). I have a Windows 7 installation DVD, but when I tell my computer to boot from the CD/DVD Drive in the BIOS, it doesn't work. It bypasses it and starts booting Ubuntu instead.

I have used this Windows installation disk in the past, so I know that it works.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu Micah! The problem you're facing has nothing to do with Ubuntu. It's either the CD, or your BIOS/laptop. The only thing we can do is link you to this question: [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. You should do the following.

You may go to BIOS and force your startup to be done right from the DVD-ROM(there is such an option right above the boot order). Select the DVD-ROM above this boot order and you re ready to go.

But, I can not understand why to prefer Windows over Ubuntu or any other Unix distro to tell the truth. Answer me when you have sucessfully formatted your PC with Windows.

Kind regards.